# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined when i try to patchValue in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

How I can `patchValue` in **ngOnInit()** Function , I try to patch the value snapshot from link into a html select but it's not working.

NB:
**onTest()** when I try with separate function it's working very well

```
@ViewChild('FomrElm',{static:false}) RentForm : NgForm;

ngOnInit() {
  if( this.route.snapshot.params['brand'] != null ){
    console.log('::'+this.route.snapshot.params['brand']);
    this.RentForm.form.patchValue({
      Brand : 'Peugeot'
    })
    this.brand_V = this.route.snapshot.params['brand'] ;
    this.model_V = this.route.snapshot.params['model'] ;
  } 

  onTest(){
    this.RentForm.form.patchValue({
      Brand : 'Peugeot'
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form hasn't been initalized yet in ngOnInit of the parent component.  You can implement `AfterViewInit` and have access to the initialized form of the `ViewChild`

Below is a stackblitz for your review

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  
  @ViewChild(UserFormComponent)
  public userForm: UserFormComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // The form in ViewChild will not be null.
    console.log(this.userForm);
  }

}
```

See the console in of the stackblitz below to see the difference.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shwrtx
>
> https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: The same Issue , when i submit normal is okey but when i get param's on link , there is a issue

Comment: @ElAmSouhail I've updated the stackblitz to patch the url params into the form.